# Can I assign/move a new value into a unique_ptr inside a tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, unique-ptr

The need to do this has arisen since I want `run` to use all the other tuple elements. Basically, I have a vector of these tuples to form a kind of table. I couldn't figure out myself how to properly do this.

**Edit:** Apparently the previous, simplified code gives a different error, so ignore that. This code here is how I have it in my code. (Sorry)

```
class GUI {
    using win_t = std::tuple<sf::RenderWindow&, Container&, std::unique_ptr<std::thread>, std::condition_variable>;
    enum { WINDOW, CONT, THREAD, CV }

    std::vector<win_t> windows;        

    void run(win_t &win);

    win_t &addWindow(sf::RenderWindow & window, Container & c) {
        windows.emplace_back(std::forward_as_tuple(window, c, nullptr, std::condition_variable()));
        win_t &entry = windows.back();
        std::get<GUI::THREAD>(entry) = std::make_unique<std::thread>(&GUI::run, this, entry); // error is on this line
        return entry;
    }
}
```

And the Error I'm getting:

```
Error   C2280   'std::tuple<sf::RenderWindow &,Container &,std::unique_ptr<std::thread,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::condition_variable>::tuple(const std::tuple<sf::RenderWindow &,Container &,std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::condition_variable> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function dpomodorivs c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\tuple    75`
```

Comment: Did you try the above?  What went wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and include what the errors you encountered were.

Comment: Sorry. Is this better now?

Comment: @snowflake Notice that this code doesn't even match the original code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Take a closer look at the error you're getting, substituting out the types:

```
Error   C2280   'std::tuple<Ts...>::tuple(const std::tuple<Ts...>&)': attempting to reference a deleted function dpomodorivs c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\tuple    75`
```

You're trying to use the copy constructor on your tuple, which is noncopyable (due to the `unique_ptr` and `condition_variable`). On that line, that is happening here:

```
std::make_unique<std::thread>(&GUI::run, this, entry)
```

Or more specifically, in the underlying `std::thread` constructor call. `entry` isn't copyable, but the `thread` constructor copies all of its arguments internally. Even if `entry` *were* copyable, this isn't want you want anyway since `run()` will then be called with a reference to `thread`'s copy and not with the specific `entry` you want.

For that, you need [`std::ref()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
std::make_unique<std::thread>(&GUI::run, this, std::ref(entry))
```